# In Rails, how can I detect if a model is being changed via nested attributes vs. on its own?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Let's say I have a model `Checklist` that `has_many :items` and `accepts_nested_attributes_for :items`.

I want to know in some Item callbacks and validations if it is being updated via nested attributes or just on its own. (This can e.g. let me optimise by running certain hooks only once when multiple Items are edited via the Checklist.)

How can I detect this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what seems like a pretty good way.

I add a flag to Item, and override Checklist `items_attributes=` to set that flag.

Item:

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  # …

  attr_accessor :updated_via_checklist

  after_save do
    if updated_via_checklist
      # Do nothing. The Checklist does something in batch.
    else
      do_something_for_just_this_item
    end
  end
end
```

Checklist:

```
class Checklist < ApplicationRecord
  # …

  after_save do
    do_something_in_batch(items)
  end

  def items_attributes=(value)
    return_value = super
    items.each { _1.updated_via_checklist = true }
    return_value
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

You can detect if an object is being updated via nested attributes by checking the object's _nested_attributes flag

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v6.1/2_3_release_notes.html#nested-attributes

Comment: Thanks! Could you give some more info here? I'm not seeing what you describe documented on that page. I've tried searching for it in the code of Rails 6.1 as well as edge Rails with no luck. I can't make it work in a console: `NameError: undefined local variable or method \`_nested_attributes' for #<Item:0x000055c70499dee8>`

Answer (score -1):

Or just a couple of lines shorter:

```rb
# checklist.rb

def items_attributes=(value)
  super(value.merge!({updated_via_checklist: true}))
end
```

Comment: Thank you! For slight tweaks to existing solutions, a comment might be more appropriate than a new answer – but I appreciate it. Either way I'm afraid this won't work – the `value` can be an array of hashes, so that would need to be taken into account. And the use of `merge!` instead of `merge` is inadvisable – that mutates the `value` object, which this method doesn't own, so that could cause bugs.